# PHP contact form sends empty emails

Tags: php, html, email

I can't understand why my PHP contact form sends empty emails.
Please, help me to figure out where the problem is.

HTML form code:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Имя">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Номер телефона">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Ваши пожелания"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$phone      = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'hello@helloschool.ru';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

After I removed '@' My Error Log says:

> [Sun Aug 27 21:41:14 2017] [warn] [client 89.169.84.160] mod_fcgid:
>   stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in
>   /var/www/u0337516/data/www/helloschool.ru/sendemail.php on line 2,
>   referer: http://helloschool.ru/

JS code (main.js):

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Отправка заявки...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Спасибо, что оставили заявку! Мы свяжемся с вами как можно скорее.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for a newbie question.

Comment: Check if post form is submitted.

Comment: You're never going to have great success using PHP's mail function. Save yourself lots of headaches and time wasted, and start using SMTP. Make it easy by using a pre-built solution like Swiftmailer.

Comment: Why the `@`s, were you getting undefined notices?

Comment: Using @ is a bad practice. It will also suppress important errors that needs to be fixed.

Comment: in addition to the sound advice in above comments, start reading your PHP error log, it helps you develop with less headaches

Comment: I removed @ but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have an error in php code. Parameter `headers` must be a string.

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

must be

```
$headers  = '';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}"."\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

2) Your `message` is in Russian, but codepage iso-8859-1 supports only Latin alphabet and you need Cyrillic. Try use codepage of your HTML (I think it is Windows-1251 or UTF-8).

3) you have an error in your `javascript`.

```
$.ajax({
         url: form.attr('action')});
```

must be

```
$.ajax({
         url: form.attr('action'),
         data: form.serialize(),
         method: "POST"});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, but it still doesn't work after I made these changes. Could it be something else? Thank you

Comment: @StanislavDobryakov I think this is `codepage` issue. As I can see you use Russian language for `message`, but `codepage` iso-8859-1 supports only English. try choose another codepage (Windows-1251, UTF-8). Try email English message, not Russian.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, didn't work. By the way, my error log: [Sun Aug 27 21:41:14 2017] [warn] [client 89.169.84.160] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/u0337516/data/www/helloschool.ru/sendemail.php on line 2, referer: http://helloschool.ru/

Comment: @StanislavDobryakov looks like array `$_POST` is empty. You send empty message because of this. I think this is server issue.

Comment: @StanislavDobryakov try add `print_r($_POST);print_r($_SERVER);` at begin of your php file. and look at result.

Comment: What should happen? Nothing changed.

Comment: @StanislavDobryakov you have an error in your javascript, file main.js. you haven't send any data to the server.